# Find $f(x)$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-a}^a \frac{|y+x|^p}{1+y^2} f(x) dx dy<\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Can we find a  non-negative function $f(x)$ on $[-a,a]$ such that 
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-a}^a \frac{|y+x|^p}{1+y^2} f(x) dx dy <\infty 
\end{align}
and can be computed in closed form?

Note we must restrict ourselves to $p \in [0,1)$ otherwise the integral is infinity.

I tried and example when $f(x)$ is a constant (which I thought would be the simplest) but could not find a close form expression integrate.

Comment: Actually you need $p<1.$

Comment: @zhw. Yes, you right. Will Correct. Any idea how to find such a function $f$?

Answer (score 1):

Any $f$ integrable on $[-a,a]$ will give convergence for $0\le p <1.$ That's because $|y+x|^p \le |y|^p + |x|^p.$ It then follows that your integral is no more than

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-a}^a \frac{|y|^p+|x|^p}{1+y^2}\, f(x)\, dx\, dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-a}^a \frac{|y|^p}{1+y^2} \, f(x)\, dx\, dy + \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-a}^a \frac{|x|^p}{1+y^2} \, f(x)\, dx\, dy
\end{align},$$

and both integrals on the right are finite. Computing your integral in closed form is a different matter.